# How to implement a leaderboard with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, leaderboard

anyone can help me with this leaderboard? I make one game on LibGDX and now I try implement a hight score system, so for that I one leaderboard. I search in differen sites or videos but for nothing :(. 
I would be very glad if someone could give me a site with tutorials either be one ready implemented.

Comment: Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) center as a start.

Comment: I don't anythink for show.. because I don't find anythink what works? :(

Comment: search for shephertz leaderboard, or parse leaderboard

Comment: Don't make your game from different parts of code from different sources. Creating leaderboard with libgdx is quite similar to creating leaderboard without it. Here you should begin https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can find a step by step tutorial.](http://theinvader360.blogspot.ie/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html) It is an old post and Google has changed google-play-services since then, but in the comments you will see the respective changes you will need to make.

BTW...it is working for me and once you get working, it will take you less then 5min to integrate it with any other game.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run Android platform specific code, [here](http://carlorodriguez.github.io/blog/2014/10/05/android-platform-specific-code-with-libgdx/) you can find how to do so, then you can use native Android code as usual.